# Does $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1 - e^{- \lambda_n}) \lt \infty$ implies $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lambda_n \lt \infty$?

Tags: analysis

Here $\lambda_n \ge 0, \forall n \ge 1$.

From the inequality $1 - e^{-x} \le x$ we conclude if $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lambda_n \lt \infty$ then $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1 - e^{- \lambda_n}) \lt \infty$.

But, how about the inverse?

Comment: $1-e^{-x} \geq x/(1+x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $1 - e^{-x} = x + O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$, we get $\sum 1 - e^{-\lambda_n} < \infty$ if and only if $\sum \lambda_n < \infty$. If you're not comfortable with asymptotics, use the limit comparison test:
$$\frac{1 - e^{-x}}{x} \to 1 \qquad \text{ as } x \to 0.$$